# updating a json column is taking too much time

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, spring-data-jpa

I am using mssql, and in 1 column I am keeping everything as a json string. It has multiple nested arrays.

When I wanted to update the json column by its id, it's taking more than 4 seconds, I am using spring data jpa.

```
@Service

public void updateFeed(Feed feed, String customerId) throws IOException {

    StopWatch stop = new StopWatch();

    String custttString = customerRepository.getCustomer(customerId);

        // some manipulations

    stop.start();
    customerRepository.updateCustomerWithFeed(custJson,customerId);
    stop.stop();
    System.out.println(stop.getTotalTimeMillis());

}

@Repository

@Modifying
@Query(value="update Customers set configJSON = ?1 where CustomerId = ?2", nativeQuery= true)
@Transactional
void updateCustomerWithFeed(String custJson, String custId);
```

This is taking more than 4 seconds,which is too much.

Any help, why it is taking this much time?

Comment: What is `Customers` schema? Are there any indexes on `CustomerId`? What is custJson size? Add more info to your question so that you will be able to get a correct answer.

Comment: Customers table...3 colums are there...I'd which is auto created column....jsonConfig nvarchar(Max) in which Jon data is getting stored and customer ID column...cuatJson size will be some KB...NO customer ID column is not indexed column

Comment: Should I make the Json column as indexed or only customer ID column is sufficient?